# makefile double dollar sign in user defined function

Tags: macros, makefile, call, dollar-sign

In chapter 8 (P150) of [Managing Projects with GNU Make](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/), the author introduces `Tromey’s Way`.

```
define make-depend
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -M $1 | \
  $(SED) 's,\($$(notdir $2)\) *:,$$(dir $2) $3: ,' > $3.tmp
  $(MV) $3.tmp $3
endef

%.o: %.c
    $(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

My understanding of double dollar sign, `$$(notdir $2)` and `$$(dir $2)`, is that it is used to escape `$` so that it's expanded later. However, we are expect it to operator on `$2` in here, right?

I suspect it's one error, but I couldn't find it on errata. Is it really one mistake, or I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, used like this it's an error to double the dollar signs.  The only time it wouldn't hurt to double them is if you were going to send the results of the `call` function to something like `eval` which expand the results again.  But there's no need for it in either case.

I should point out that this example, while better than most other methods, is somewhat deprecated these days.  The GCC compiler has options which can generate pretty much exactly the makefile dependency output you want without postprocessing, and while still creating the object file at the same time.  This is actually significantly more efficient because you don't have to run the compiler twice every time you compile.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. The above sed processing is to address make restart problem. It's add dependency files as the target of a list of header and source files, like `list.o list.d: list.c list.h`. I looked up gcc manual, but I couldn't find the `-M<something>` option to do this.

Comment: You don't want the `.d` file to be a target when you use this method.  Why do you want to add it?

Comment: Actually, I want `.d` as the target, because of some benefit introduce in that book (P151), as one way to avoid make restart. Summarized in here: `.d` and `.o` are logically connected in this way, and missing `.d` indicates missing `.o`. Therefore, we could just ignore missing `.d`, and proceed.